# Additional Info For Some Users

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms

I am looking to add some additional content to users that should be required for users of type X 
example: Sales Associate's 
require: Profile Picture

just breaking into Orchard, i have done some looking for something like this just no luck so far.

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: There are user profile modules available on the gallery.

Comment: i can add content to all users, what i am looking to do is add some additional content to specific user types. example: all users have a first/last name. customer service users will have a phone number with an extension

Comment: Right, but I don't see how the presence of the additional data is a problem. Can't you just not use it for users that don't require it?

Comment: Definitely could. It's just that I'm not the one going to be admin on the site. Want to give them a way of adding users of type X and then showing the extra content once type X is selected. Was trying to do this with little code but am digging into the source as this seems like its going to be the way.

Comment: There will also be multiple user types each needing to have additional content specific to the type. After reviewing the documentation I think I have an approach that will work. Need to make a little more progress before I post anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every user in Orchard is of type `User` - there is no distinction. So you may approach the problem twofold:

1. Create your own content types to describe various users. By default there is one type in Orchard that describes a user - `"User"`.

   In order to make it work you'd need to write your own version of `Orchard.Users` module that would take that information into account. It may be quite a bit of work though as you'd need to override any piece of functionality that's there that uses the hardcoded `"User"` type. Best and cleanest solution, but also the most complex.
2. Use a single content part attached to `"User"` type, similar to how the profile modules (eg. [Contrib.Profile](https://orchardprofile.codeplex.com/)) work. The distinction between different user types can be done on the driver level. You're free to return different content for a given part, based on some custom logic (eg. the stored value describing "user type"). Lot less flexibility than the first approach (all other parts attached to a user will be shared by everyone), but also lot less coding.

Comment: Sounds resonable, thank you will be trying this over the weekend.

Comment: im going about this the wrong way. great answer but i need to change how i think about some of this stuff. Im, getting there!